# Free Result Set Data mysqli_result::free

Tags: php, mysql

From my studies I understand that one should free the result set data, after manipulating/using the Query data. I am trying to use the `mysqli_result::free` pdo in the following code context:

```
if ($result) 
   { $change = $result[0][9];
 $change = $change+1;
 $sql='UPDATE users SET visits = :visit WHERE username = :username';
 $q=$dbh->prepare($sql);
 $q->bindValue(':username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $q->bindValue(':visit',$change,PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $q->execute();
  // initiate SESSION and Set USER SESSION Variables through the  --session_handler.php
require ('./includes/session_handler.php');
//Free the Query Result set to free memory on the database handler
$result->free();
// direct registered users to MEMBER_ZONE.php for registered users interface
header('Location: member_zone.php');    
                                exit(); 
   }
```

I receive the message : 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::free() in...

I have researched at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php as well as on Google and found no example code to further elucidate its application.

On this site the examples : [mysqli_result::free increase php memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31767536/mysqli-resultfree-increase-php-memory-usage)
Here it is confusing: shouldn't in this code the `$row` be freed?

And here [Are mysqli_result::free and mysqli_stmt::free_result the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004366/are-mysqli-resultfree-and-mysqli-stmtfree-result-the-same)

Here two forms of `free_result()` and `free()` are used together.

I cannot seem to find my error or a clear usage example. I would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was using the `$q->free()` on a result, which never came, because I was updating the database, not requesting a result. The syntax seemed to be correctly used. It was my order of use which I think was wrong.